# string pattern involving or statements on either end

Tags: r

hi i'm hoping to look into file names in  read and pull out (A|B)(....)(C|D) pattern from the file names where .... is a numeric that ends up in the column. Code below works but when i try to add an or to either end of the pattern i get this error:

Error: `regex` should define 1 groups; found.

file names are many but one pattern is Y####.D and the other is 1####.P. Id like the #### for both to read into the column.

this works for one pattern:

```
data = tibble(File = filenames) %>%
    extract(File, "Site", "Y(....)\\.D", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(Data = lapply(File, read_csv)) %>%
    unnest(Data) %>%
    select(-File)
```

This yields the group error above.

```
data = tibble(File = filenames) %>%
    extract(File, "Site", "(Y|1)(....)\\.(D|P)", remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(Data = lapply(File, read_csv)) %>%
    unnest(Data) %>%
    select(-File)
```

thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example i.e. `filenames`

Comment: possibly `"[Y1](....)\\.[DP]"`, but beware, this also matches 1...D, and Y...P

Comment: filenames <- c("ACSDP5Y2011.DP05", "DECENNIALSF12010.P1")